# Typescript match first uppercased letter on type level

Tags: typescript

I want to transform a string literal from camelCase to snake_case, like:

```js
type CamelCaseStr = "helloWorldAgain"
type _ = ToSnakeCase<CamelCaseStr> // "hello_world_again"
```

Here is my Solution:

```js
type str = "helloWorldAgain";
type UpperCollection = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
type Chars<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}` ? Char | Chars<Rest> : never;
type UpperLetters = Chars<UpperCollection>;

type ToSnakeCase<T extends string> = 
T extends `${infer LowerStr}${UpperLetters}${infer AfterFirstBigLetter}` ? 
T extends `${LowerStr}${infer WithFirstBigLetter}` ? 
`${LowerStr}_${ToSnakeCase<Uncapitalize<WithFirstBigLetter>>}` : 
LowerStr : 
T;
type _ = ToSnakeCase<str>; 
// type _ = "helloWorld_again" | "helloWorld_world_again" | "hello_again" | "hello_world_again"
```

I attempted to extract a `LowerStr` until firstly encountered an uppercased letter, therefore extract first capitalized str, then `Uncapitalize` it and use `ToSnakeCase` again. However, the result is wrong, so I wrote some test code.

```js
type TestToSnakeCase<T extends string> = 
T extends `${infer LowerStr}${UpperLetters}${infer AfterFirstBigLetter}` ? 
T extends `${LowerStr}${infer WithFirstBigLetter}` ? 
[LowerStr, WithFirstBigLetter] : 
never
: T;
type __ = TestToSnakeCase<str>; 
// type __ = ["helloWorld" | "hello", "Again" | "WorldAgain"];
```

The problem seems to be reduced down to shut discrimination. I searched and found this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) useful, with which I tried again.

```js
type ShutDiscrimination<T extends string> = 
[T] extends [`${infer LowerStr}${UpperLetters}${infer AfterFirstBigLetter}`] ? 
[T] extends [`${LowerStr}${infer WithFirstBigLetter}`] ? 
`${LowerStr}_${ShutDiscrimination<Uncapitalize<WithFirstBigLetter>>}` : 
LowerStr : 
T;
type ___ = ShutDiscrimination<str>;
// type ___ = "helloWorld_again" | "helloWorld_worldAgain" | "hello_again" | "hello_worldAgain"
```

Is there anything critical I missed to solve this problem? I hope I expressed my idea well, formatting is quite cumbersome:)

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOUC8UBEALCAbLB7A6rvFgCYCCA5gIYCWAdqgNwCwAUKJFAKpiTwDCuHBADGwGrjrI0ZAEL8AIgFEAYgHEAEgEkAUgGkAMgFkAcgHkACgEUASgGUAKlwBq+ABoBNAFpM2HaPzoVPAwADwOUBAAHsAQdCQwsAj0FAB80hHRsfGJAAYAJADe9ABmEIiBwQC+RaXlUDYQcFW5UAD8UJWIAD6dQSGhjXDpAFxQdBAAbuUs7ODQPHwGEMCxIdJdYYvlgsJiEnSps37zUA64dnRUANYQ-FQwEOGRMXEJSfAp6Shsma85UAKxToZUQBlwAHdynYEDVCtt4MtVuUYHC6ogyCU1ioaCFgLIaBQkWsWu0oL8Xtl3kDwVD4DD4GiQfV8DRgOgcXiCUSViTWm02DTIdDYQB9IrnS43O4PJ5cOgiKhgNlULA0ABeT1Z7M5cG5xPKqVSpLYY1pIvgprOxzmnAcTWAkqut3uj2eWTeiTgnzoaQylM9gNqzLBwvpsKKCINISZoKgmOxuL1hOjpI6fypeSK5vDjODce1HKT+JTvPKaagAG0cwyADRQQu6ks85HwAC6UDGE2mltYYwcs38UDs6AArsAFDQYCJPgBbehUcSSd3-d7er7SNiVhwdj0AytA9FQGsR+G8crR1H5+oJ8pN-Vlxm5DsdLc7gP7oV0hmxllsotcqWrYtC+5KsF+FpVOKhQjuOk7TnOC5LnQoTyoqyrAKqGpav+95AWsRqkmMbAnogxGsAObAnJwooZBczoym63pHNR0CirRKD2nATrSq6TzMYOpzsRxw5jhOU4zjQ85XMhoQCUAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are using `UpperLetters` directly in the conditional clause where you infer.   Because `UpperLetters` can only be a single character, you should instead infer the character then check if it `extends` `UpperLetters`.  This will flatten the unions you see.

```
type UpperLetter = "a" | "b";
type Parse<S extends string> = S extends
  `${infer $Start}${infer $UpperLetter}${infer $Rest}`
  ? $UpperLetter extends UpperLetter ? true : false
  : false;
```

Anyways, I attempted the problem myself without using a static `UpperLetter` union by checking if `Capitalize<S>` is equal to `S`.  Here it is:

```
type CamelToSnakeCase<S extends string, $Acc extends string = ""> =
  //
  S extends `${infer $Ch}${infer $Rest}`
    ? S extends Capitalize<S>
      ? CamelToSnakeCase<$Rest, `${$Acc}_${Lowercase<$Ch>}`>
    : CamelToSnakeCase<$Rest, `${$Acc}${$Ch}`>
    : $Acc;

type foo = CamelToSnakeCase<"helloAwesomeWorld">; // "hello_awesome_world"
type foo2 = CamelToSnakeCase<"">; // ""
type foo3 = CamelToSnakeCase<"bruhSOCool">; // "bruh_s_o_cool"

type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string, $Acc extends string = ""> =
  //
  S extends `${infer $Ch}${infer $Rest}`
    ? $Ch extends "_"
      ? $Rest extends `${infer $Ch}${infer $Rest}`
        ? SnakeToCamelCase<$Rest, `${$Acc}${Capitalize<$Ch>}`>
      : ""
    : SnakeToCamelCase<$Rest, `${$Acc}${$Ch}`>
    : $Acc;

type asdf = SnakeToCamelCase<"hello_awesome_world">; // "helloAwesomeWorld"
type asdf2 = SnakeToCamelCase<"bruh_s_o_cool">; // "bruhSOCool"
type asdf3 = SnakeToCamelCase<"">; // ""
type asdf4 = SnakeToCamelCase<"so_cool_bro">; // "soCoolBro"
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWwgGwCoHsDKA7OBrCeAZwgB5MoIAPYCbAEyKiOACcBLbAcwBooASAIIBjYZRp1GzNpy5QAvFABESgHwKAsACgoUAPR7tuitVoMmAA34BvTgDMIrATAAWAXxv3HAgEoQWbhZGulAA-FAmEuawcGDswHDI7ABeZJiqwSFhMUhoWLgExGT8fix8VtZCom4A+jYAMugA7o7CcCSk-K6qgRk6IQBcOSgYOPiE7cWlwOU2VcIela69mVBD8wDc2tqgkFB26OgKw3ljhZOkSi4oyOiCLUToSADq6KzI9Gob+nrK18i3GpwB5PCA1JpvD5KHbgaAHdAAJmO8FyowKEw6KlU3wMymhWl2cMOAGZkYgRvlxkVLgAjVgAVxcmAA8jBDsgvj9lHTGTUiDV0DVhOz8TC9mcIBgUShqZEzFIWBxuHx5uJ5UxFbJjljNP0DME5ZJLJ5sA4nF13Cazb5-MBAqtwha1UblDV8VldI7ps7ohUvObllbvCVbfb+h7shKpeTkNSQ2UoBV5ot4HEEklUp1uitw4M8ashlH0NLYxd4zNE3MRAs5ssLH0sutq1stGLoO16HZjkWS9SrjdBcD-KDwZDPtiuf2AXcQS8x-jCVAO3YkYoezG+zyXHyBUKRRPcUotyy2egOW2l0RO6S1+jo7k+5zDwvYZfOwAWbt34sbi5KR57meNR0ugT6-P+xbsgAQqwoHaEAA)

Edit: It was not the union that fixed your code.  It was the fact that I inferred the next letter when I did `${infer $Ch}${infer $Rest}` then checked if it was uppercase via `Capitalize`.  You were doing `${infer LowerStr}${UpperLetters}${infer AfterFirstBigLetter}` which computes the value of the string for each branch in `UpperLetters` which results in having issues with multiple types for `LowerStr` and `AfterFirstBigLetter`.  Here's an example:

```
type UpperLetter = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" // ..

// This is going to go through each computed type in the extends clause and come up with multiple 
// answers in the union for after the various characters.

type bad = "ABCD" extends `${string}${UpperLetter}${infer $After}` ? $After : never; // "" | "D" | "BCD" | "CD"

// Now, let's fix the code by writing an infer character to force the extends clause to only have one possible combination.
// This can be done by replacing `UpperLetter` with `infer $Ch` because any `string` / `infer $Ch` and removing the leading
// `${string}` part.

type fixed = "ABCD" extends `${infer $Ch}${infer $After}` ? $Ch extends UpperLetter ? $After : never : never; // "BCD"
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmkCcAyFjAgqBeKAiAgrlAD54BCRpuAwpXgCJED0TUAdGwFCctQAqACwCWAZyiioAcwD2QgHaSowaVJXABCaQFdJAqBACGAYz1HpAWzBb0AEyXho8pQOgQAHujk2xRgDYGtEWgDLygzc2gtMCgAdyF1KHMtX2AhMF9oHlYQkRiMMSd1SLkhaTkoADNpTAMK9EwiqAA3AwRSwLCBVuN6kS5OUEgoACMDOxwCMmpGfQ8ILzEAAwASAG8RYDaFAF81uEQUNAxd1fkKjChl-DrjxagAfkvr+qgALig5CCaMAG4oXlwdFwMyoUxBeGmuG4vAActIYgAaKAZYAAcjEFSEbmc0DMNmgwxAsTaqQUUBC4jk50wJm6Rheykq1SM0Ea7k83jC-kCrJUZV8RK63ygZWgYGkIhEQmGGTCFmG8gMqTKXF4ggkRgpw2gNlFIyJCAg6WM8kUi32GEO9TucQSizOF2W1AEd21mp55LkRMWGy2kjurHtVMdzruITshvM0iappxyMMNlNWSgK3Wm1N2zuYFawH6g2gmLcEHGeHwYKI7PmnNTDswToEJ1rTxuCEzD0uztmHLEFuQqBejyuLbeHy+F3en2+CD+APLQA)

Comment: Inferring the uppercased letter instead of using `UpperLetters` directly is exactly the critical part I missed! BTW, can you explain why in the doc, wrapping union into a tuple can disable discriminated feature?

Comment: @crazyones110 I have updated my answer.  Hopefully it helps explain things a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, inspired by @sno2

I've focused there is only just one way comparing 'target character' with recursions for no `Alphabet Collection`.

```
export type CamelCaseToSnakeCase<
  T extends string,
  Joiner extends '' | '_' = ''
> = T extends `${infer Character}${infer Rest}`
  ? Character extends Uppercase<Character>
    ? `${Joiner}${Lowercase<Character>}${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<Rest, '_'>}`
    : `${Character}${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<Rest, '_'>}`
  : '';
```